# (JavaScript & HTML) How to target a specific input tag through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that allows the user to create a todo list.  Right now I allowed the user to be able to type in any task they want.  I have the javascript that calls a function when you press the "Enter" key on your keyboard.  However, I only want the user to be able to call this function only when they are creating a new task.  So I was wondering how to target a specific  tag in my HTML code using Javascript.

**This is the Javascript code that I tried:**

```
$("input[newtsak][name$='newtask']").onload = function(){
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13){
          alert('hello')}})
 }
```

**Original Code:**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
```

JS:

```
 window.onload = function(){
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13){
          alert('hello')}})
 }
```

Comment: Your function seems okay but your selector query is incorrect. Try this. $("input#newtask[type=text][name=newtask]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a selector string, the syntax `[newtsak]` selects an element which has an *attribute* of `newtsak`, eg `<input newtsak>`.

Because your input has an ID, and IDs are unique in the document (or, at least *should* be), consider just using that ID to select it, and listen for a `keydown` event fired at the element.

You also should use `$(() => {` to wait for the DOM to be ready, not `$(someElement).onload`:

```js
$(() => {
  $('#newtask').on('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      console.log('enter pressed');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<input placeholder="something else">
```

Unless you're using `name` attribute on the input for something specific, feel free to remove it, the unique ID is already enough to select the element. `type="text"` and `value=""` are not necessary either.

```
<input spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should let the `input` element listen keydown event, not window.
try this .

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name$='newtask']").on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            alert(123)
        }
    })
})
```